# HELP! Fatal Error? I can't access the Dashboard. How do I regain access?

Tags: fatal-error

I was trying to make my friend's website more mobile friendly, so I tried activating a plugin. The next thing I know, I can't even log into the Dashboard and it says:

> **Fatal error**: Call to undefined function `wp_enqueue_media()` in `/../wp-content/plugins/mobile-navigation-menu/includes/admin/admin_menu.php` on *line 33*

Comment: If you can't get into your admin dashboard, try ( http://codex.wordpress.org/FAQ_Troubleshooting#How_to_deactivate_all_plugins_when_not_able_to_access_the_administrative_menus.3F) resetting the plugins folder  by FTP  (http://codex.wordpress.org/FTP_Clients ).

Comment: Thanks, Tara... So, basically, I need to educate myself on what FTP is and figure out how to download and install this software just to access the site so I can teach myself to delete or disable this random plugin?

Comment: see my comment.  My answer will work for you, try to get hosting access.  forget the FTP method for now.

Comment: You can also use your web-host's cPanel or whatever file management application your host provides (no Dashboard access required). So ask you hosting provider what file management application they provide.

Answer (score 1):

disable the plugin.

Either by going into the dashboard and disabling it or by going to the files through ftp .   If by ftp you'll need to go to your www/wp-content/plugins directory.  and then remove the navigation-menu entirely.

Comment: I can;t even access the dashboard. Every time i try to login it gives me the fatal error note

Comment: Is there any guidance you could give me on this process?

Comment: @JoshuaC If you contact your host they may be able to help bring your site back online. There are also many tutorials online on how to access websites via FTP.

Comment: login to ftp or to hosting control panel and then to Web space Explorer or file manager and then go to your plug-ins directory and delete that plugin

Comment: rudtek.... is there any way I could get your help with this? how do i log into ftp?

Comment: did you figure out how to login?  You'll likely be more suited to get into the hosting control panel and make the change there.  Who is hosting?  I'll try to get specific for you.

Answer (score -1):

You will need to ask you friend to give you the ftp servername, login username and password. With these you can login to the fileserver. When logged in you need to navigate into wp-content and then into plugins. Since this clearly happened after installing the "mobile-navigation-menu" plugin, you'll have to disable or delete it.

I have had luck by simply renaming the folder that contains the plugin. Just put some underscores before the actual name, or insert a few aditional letters at the beginning of the name. if this doesn't work you will need to delete the plugin from the server. After this all should be back to normal.

Let me know if you have any more questions.

Comment: why is my answer downvoted ? I've solved this kind of errors/problems exactly this way ...

Comment: probably because it was the same answer i provided...

Comment: Instead of just downvoating, some explanation could have been given. In a note.

Comment: i'm simply guessing...trying to help.  I've had similar things happen to me.  :(